# Limiting words in a text box

Tags: c#, html, textbox

I'm trying to create a text box in c# that will only contain 100 words and after the 100th word no other text can be input into the box.

Comment: Try to rephrase that as a question that might be useful to SO.

Comment: You sure you don't mean _characters_? @I4V has a point!

Comment: I'm trying to make a box for essays so I did mean words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple approach which might be inaccurate because it replaces consecutive white-spaces with one:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] words = textBox1.Text.Split();
    int wordCount = words.Length;
    if (wordCount > 100)
        textBox1.Text = string.Join(" ", words.Take(100));
}
```

instead of the `String.Join` you could replace it with the old text:

```
private string oldText;
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] words = textBox1.Text.Split();
    int wordCount = words.Length;
    if (wordCount > 100)
        textBox1.Text = oldText;
    else
        oldText = textBox1.Text;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Tim but is there any way that it will stop them from typing anything after the 100th word? You can continue to type with the code but when you deselect the box it deletes every thing after the 100th word. This is a problem because this form will be used by students writing essays and we don't want them to lose half their essay.

Comment: You  could disable the Textbox after the 100th word.

Comment: I'm new to programming with C#/HTML and I'm wondering if disabling the textbox would permanently disable it or would the user be able to delete a word and add another?

Answer (score 0):

On the TextChanged event of the textbox, count the ocurrences of white spaces and line breaks. If they're greater than 99, don't allow the text to change. You'll have to keep a copy of its text in another variable so that you can revert to that if the user inputs thr 101th word.